# Every element is big - stretched (font, pcitures, map...)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps

I have two projects and one of them have every element very very big. This is screen with normal size map and alert dialog:

[image]

And this is where everything is big (same tablet 10):

[image]

I have no idea what is wrong with the other project. Second project is good looking on `480x800`, but on bigger screen is bigger fond, alert, map (with controllers) and just everything. What could be the problem? I tried the same XML and it is still different. Where can I modify something and it will be OK? Thank you very much for answers.

Comment: what `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` values do you have in the `AndroidManifest`? Compatibility mode could be a problem...

Comment: wow thank You very much! It works! :) But, now I have another problem :( My application have to be working on Android 1.5 and Android 4.2.2. It works great when it have: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>`. But that way It's not runnable on sdk 3. Is there any way to use it properly on new android and it is still possible to run it on old device? It would be really great - I don't want to have two separate projects.

Comment: you can change only `targetSdkVersion` to 11 and leave `minSdkVersion` as it is. `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />`

Comment: On 1.5 there is no such thing as targetSdkVersion :( `Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - <uses-sdk> tag appears after <application> tag
 - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'targetSdkVersion' in package 'android'
 - Not targeting the latest versions of Android; compatibility modes apply. Consider testing and updating this version. Consult the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES javadoc 
  for details.`

Comment: try to change your project SDK to android 1.6 or higher

Comment: It have to work on 1.5... It's for special system. :(

Comment: setting project SDK to android 1.6+ doesn't mean that application cann't be run on android 1.5. Application will work fine on 1.5 as long as you have `android:minSdkVersion="3"` and don't use any 1.6+ specific features

Comment: Sorry I did not know that. As you said I change SDK in Name `project -> properties -> Android -> Android 1.6` and in manifest is `<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8" android:minSdkVersion="3" />`. and now it's working on both devices. Thank You very very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have enabled screen compatibility mode in the second project. So you need to disable it. It can be done in several ways:

1. Set `targetSdkVersion` to 11 or higher in your `AndroidManifest`.

   ```
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
   ```
2. Or explicitly declare that your application supports xlarge screens.

   ```
   <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
   ```

Here you can find more detailed infromation [Screen Compatibility Mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html)

Comment: Thank you, yes it's problem with sdk and it helps a lot :) But as I reply on comment above, I have problem that my application have to work on android 1.5. Everything mentioned here is working from 1.6. It's for one very old machine and also for android 4.2.2 so I don't know what to do now, so it will work on old android and new one will be "pretty" and not stretched.

Comment: but do you really need to support Android 1.5? According to http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html android 1.6 is only used by 0.2% of android devices and android 1.5 is not even mentioned...

Comment: Sadly, yes. It is for special system called "Funtoro" for buses and it just support android 1.5. It's my bachelor project. On that it looks good, it's 480x800. But I don't have bus so I have to test it on my Nexus and it have to be used on both devices :( So... now I don't know what to do... It have to be just one project :(

Answer (score 0):

You can declaretion dimension in the values file.

Comment: but why it's by default everything so stretched? Problem must be somewhere else, no? And when I have a lot of elements it would be a lot of work - everything change... :(